# how to route to an external url using zuul proxy filter

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-rest

i have an external url and i want to pass some request header through zuul filter to launch the application.
Can anyone please help me on this.
In my custom prefilter i have written this:

```
 @Component
public class CustomFilters extends ZuulFilter {

    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomFilters.class);


    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return "route";
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {
        logger.info("executing run ");
        RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("x-forwarded-host", "<external url>");
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("x-forwarded-proto", "https");
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("x-forwarded-port", "8800");
        ctx.addZuulRequestHeader("key", "id);

        return null;
    }
}
```

app.properties:

```
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8080
zuul.routes.books.sensitive-headers=
zuul.routes.books.path = /books/
zuul.routes.books.url = <ext url>
```

Sample Application:
This is giving me a rest url through which i am redirecting to external url  defined above in my properties file.

```
public class SampleApplication {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/check")
      public String available() {
        return "available!";
      }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SampleApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

app.properties:

```
spring.application.name=book
server.port=8090
```

Issue screenshot

[image]

Comment: any lead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      url: http://example.com/users_service
```

These simple url-routes do not get executed as a HystrixCommand, nor do they load-balance multiple URLs with Ribbon. To achieve those goals, you can specify a serviceId with a static list of servers, as follows:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    echo:
      path: /myusers/**
      serviceId: myusers-service
      stripPrefix: true

hystrix:
  command:
    myusers-service:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: ...

myusers-service:
  ribbon:
    NIWSServerListClassName: com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
    ListOfServers: http://example1.com,http://example2.com
    ConnectTimeout: 1000
    ReadTimeout: 3000
    MaxTotalHttpConnections: 500
    MaxConnectionsPerHost: 100
```

in your filter make sure that this filter should come into picture only for request with uri example1.com or example2.com by impelemting should filter method

Comment: plz take a look on above code and guide me how i can redirect to external url.i am stuck here since long time as i am newbie for zuul proxy.

Comment: since you have wriiten ribbon.eureka.enabled=false, m assuming that u are not using eureka for service discovery in that case
zuul.routes.testService.path = /path/**
zuul.routes.testService.serviceId = <urServiceAlias>
<urServiceAlias>.ribbon.listOfServers = <external url>

Comment: if above doesnt work simply add
zuul.routes.testing.path = /somepath/**
zuul.routes.testing.url = <external url>

doing this you will loose ribbon load balancing

Comment: I don't need load balancing as of now, somehow I hv to make this redirection in working condition with my request header.jyst confirm whether my zuul request headers will pass through while redirection to external url

Comment: just set zuul.routes.book.sensitiveheaders to empty list , doing so zuul will send all the headers except the ones mentioned in zuul.ignoredHeaders (if mentioned), remember sensitiveHeaders is the blacklist

Comment: it dint work..here is what i did :#zuul.addHostHeader=true
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8080
zuul.routes.testing.sensitive-headers=
zuul.routes.books.path = /check/
zuul.routes.books.url =url
and also i removed //Alter ignored headers in request from my CustomeFilter class

Comment: instead of zuul.routes.testing.sensitive-headers= 
use zuul.routes.books.sensitive-headers=

Comment: also try this in  yaml file, looks more clean and easy to debug

Comment: have added screenshot,it's not working..no headers passing through with my request while trying to access: localhost:8080/books/
 
zuul.addHostHeader=true
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
server.port=8080
zuul.routes.books.sensitive-headers=
zuul.routes.books.path = /books/
zuul.routes.books.url = <url>

Comment: also have updated my code as per suggestion if something is missed out /wrong plz suggest

Comment: oops, my bad spelling of sensitive headers should be sensitiveHeaders rather than sensitive-headers and do you need hostHeader info ,i can see that you are also adding it

Comment: thank you buddy you made my day..thank you so much for your consistent help to resolve this issue...

Comment: welcome, an upvote and accepted answer wud be nice :)